# Patch malformed error

Tags: diff, patch

```
patch: **** malformed patch at line 225: diff --git
```

the line 225 is this one :

```
diff --git a/files/etc/Compile_info.txt b/files/etc/Compile_info.txt
```

I have a many patches in one file patch and I added some lines into it, and now I got always the same error at line 225 but I did not touch at this line.

```
diff --git a/files/etc/Compile_info.txt b/files/etc/Compile_info.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000000..39635e5046
--- /dev/null
+++ b/files/etc/Compile_info.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+OpenWrt master r19541-852126680e / 2022-04-30 18:04
+---
+main      2022-04-29 8521266 mediatek: mt7629: disable mtk thermal
+luci      2022-04-30 6b3bba3 luci-app-https-dns-proxy: remove redundan
+packages  2022-04-30 cf81132 rclone: Update to 1.58.1
+routing   2022-04-27 20621cf Merge pull request #856 from stintel/bird
```

Do you see the error?

Comment: Are you attempting to apply the patch with `patch`? Please show the command that produces the error. Are the preceding and later patches in the same file applying cleanly?

Comment: For the record, `patch` on FreeBSD correctly reads the given patch and creates the file.

Comment: the command is `patch -p1 -i ../$FILESTAMP-main.patch` , and just that line is problem, but the only thing I did is to add some lines earlier but nothing at the line where the error is, seems to be caused by  `@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@` where I would need to change the number

Comment: I wonder whether the lines preceding these are problematic, like they may contain an incomplete patch?

Comment: no, impossible, I saw that post here and it seems the same problem but I dont know how to resolve it: [link] https://superuser.com/questions/1283279/what-causes-patch-malformed-patch-at-line

Comment: Consider testing by pasting the patch you show twice into a new file, then changing the `+1,6` to `1,+7` in the _first_ patch. This will cause the `patch` utility to complain about line 13: `malformed patch at line 13: diff --git ...`.  This shows that if the patch previous to the part you show is wrong, you may get a message about the `diff` line in the way you show.